# Is the current that is on the surface of the area surrounding a current carrying wire in Ampere's Law the same as what flows in the wire?

Tags: electromagnetism

I am OK with the first 3 of Maxwell's equations but on the 4th equation I need to first figure out Ampere's law. What is confusing me is the surface of the area that is surrounding the current carrying wire.

Just where is the current on the surface and is it the same as the current that flows through the wire?

(Sorry I don't have a picture here but I have not been able to find a tutorial on how to draw on Stack Exchange yet. Work in progress for me.)

Comment: Do you already follow the incomplete version (differential form being \$\operatorname{curl}\left(\vec{B}\right)=\vec{\nabla}\times\vec{B}=\mu_0\,\vec{J}\$, in the limit as the area goes to zero) and are struggling only with Maxwell's charge conservation correction? Or is the incomplete form (limited to the local relationship between current and field) already a problem? And why are you asking here and not at the physics stackexchange site -- or searching there for existing answers, already likely present there?)

Comment: Yes  thank you are right it's on the physics stackexchange. Looks good too.. Unfortunately I thought of the physics after i posted on electrical thinking Maxwell's equations was a electrical topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Just were is the current on the surface and is it the same as the current that flows through the wire?

The current flows *through* the surface, or put another way, the surface "cuts" through the current.

Imagine a soap bubble film that is attached to a ring, but has a wire passing through that soap bubble film. The soap bubble film is the surface, that "cuts" through the wire (i.e. the current). The ring that borders the soap bubble film is the closed curve.

Comment: There are no "poles" on the soap bubble film, either magnetic or electric. The magnetic field goes around in a complete closed path (like a circle). There is no North or South pole like in a bar magnet, just a direction. The current has a direction, roughly perpendicular to the film. Depending on your current convention, the electric field is either in the direction of your current, or opposite to that direction. Again, no poles here, just directions.

Comment: Thank you I got it. Last question. Is the soap bubble surface a magnetic or electric field?  I will go ahead and accept you answer. I think this is going to solve my problem.

Comment: @Sedumjoy the soap bubble is just one place where you can analyze the fields. In that soap bubble there are "rings" around the wire that represent magnetic "lines of force". Now imagine an infinite number of soap bubbles along the wire. You will have an infinite number of such magnetic lines of force, and they essentially fill up all of space. The soap bubble just lets you calculate the magnetic field in one spot.

Comment: Finally got it now. I had to review again and it makes sense now. thank you.